# Failed to fetch identity ID in Android error in AWS s3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to integrate the AWS s3 bucket in the backend of Android app but while uploading the file to the bucket, I am getting this error.

```
I/System.out: 13:16:25.476 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] DEBUG Retry - sdkRequestId: f71f62ca-3573-4d7a-9a40-9209ee8e41fa; service: Cognito Identity; operation: GetId; - request failed with non-retryable error
E/MyAmplifyApp: Upload failed
    StorageException{message=Failed to fetch identity ID, cause=null, recoverySuggestion=java.lang.Exception: Failed to get identity ID. Check if you are signed in and configured identity pools correctly.}
        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.configuration.StorageAccessLevelAwarePrefixResolver.resolvePrefix(AWSS3PluginPrefixResolver.kt:70)
        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.start$lambda-1(AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.kt:89)
        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.$r8$lambda$_oyIiFAO5jakjMzA-FOjDISO9dI(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have followed the instruction given in the official amplify doc to set up the backend.